# Over which creation did prophet sulayman have control?

Tags: prophets, jinn, animals

Prophet sulayman was given control over.

1. Jinn with the exception of ibliz.
2. Winds.
3. Animal and birds.

Are there any other creation over which he was given control by Allah because of his dua.